# How do I set up the SELinux sandbox in Debian?

Tags: debian, selinux, sandbox

I've installed SELinux in Debian sid in order to use the sandbox that locks down apps to a restricted environment, but I can't get it to work. If I try to use the sandbox command in permissive mode without any options, like `sandbox nano`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/sandbox: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

And if I try to run it with options for temporary home and tmp dirs, with or without the -X option, another error message pops up:

```
Could not set exec context to unconfined_u:unconfined_r:sandbox_x_t:s0:c236,c539.
Failed to remove directory /tmp/.sandbox-root-vfZJIt: No such file or directory
```

I have tried using the sandbox app in enforced mode, but it complains about missing type enforcement rules. I don't think that's the issue though. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It seems that the sandbox policy module isn't loaded. If I run `semodule -l` the sandbox module doesn't show up. Does anyone know how to load the sandbox policy module in Debian?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SELinux support in Debian is far from complete, with some major gaps. It appears the required policy module for this particular functionality just isn't available:

```
wouter@gangtai:~$ apt-cache show policycoreutils-sandbox
Package: policycoreutils-sandbox
Source: policycoreutils
Version: 2.4-4
```

[...]

```
Description-en: SELinux core policy utilities (graphical sandboxes)
```

[...]

```
 This package requires an additional custom policy that is not present in
 Debian.
```

you'll have to find it elsewhere.