# How do I install SELinux's sandbox utility on Linux Mint Debian Edition?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, selinux

I'm following the [Debian SELinux setup guide](http://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup#Introduction_to_SELinux_on_Debian) with my Linux Mint Debian Edition system. I installed the necessary packages:

```
sudo aptitude install selinux-basics selinux-policy-default selinux-utils policycoreutils
```

Activated SELinux and rebooted twice:

```
sudo selinux-activate
```

Checked the installation. No critical errors were reported:

```
sudo check-selinux-installation
```

When I run a simple sandbox command, e.g.

```
sandbox -X -H ~/selinux/home -T ~/selinux/tmp -t sandbox_web_t firefox
```

it tells me that the sandbox command wasn't found. I've seen [other questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36443/how-do-i-set-up-the-selinux-sandbox-in-debian) that seem to indicate with Debian, there are issues with the sandbox command, but its nonexistence isn't one of them.

Running `semodule -l` or [`locate *.pp | grep sandbox`](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=78334) doesn't list the sandbox module either, so is it simply not installed? Is there another way I can check? The version of `selinux-basics` I'm using is 0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sandbox` command was removed from the package because it was not ready for release. Here is the changelog entry for the removal from the command from the `policycoreutils` package:

- Removed sandbox because it's a new feature that we never had working, also
   removed seunshare because it's not needed and brought in an annoying
   dependency on libcgroup1
   Closes: #[678590](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678590)

It looks like it is still removed from the latest package from experimental. If you need the command, you will need to compile it from source or rebuild the Debian package without the `sandbox` removal patch.

Comment: That's really unfortunate. Since the [AppArmor equivalent](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmorSandboxing#AppArmor_Sandbox) isn't ready for general release either, what options does that leave me? Virtualization or a chroot? That's a separate question, however.